# Permutations of digits with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem and I don'tknow how to solve it. It's just a hobby, I am not a student, I am 50 years old.
The problem is the following:
I have a string of 100 digits (this can change, it is just an example).
Digits have their own frequencies, for example:
"0" appears 3 times, "1" appears 12 times, "2" appears 21 times, "3" appears 1 time, "4" appears 1 time, "5" appears 25 times, "6" appers 2 times, "7" appears 18 times, "8" appears 10 times and "9" appears 7 times.
The condition is : two consecutive digits must not be identical.

I have 3 questions:

1 - how many permutations are there with the given codition ? otherwise the answer is simple : 100! / (3! 12! 21! 25! 2! 18! 10! 7! )

2 - if I give the number of a permutation (let's say 267.245), what is he corresponding string of digits ?

3 - if I give a string, hat is the number of the permutation ?

I tried to search the answers on the net, it seems it is impossible to find the result.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I'm quite sure there is no nice solution. You should start by working out some simple cases by hand and look for patterns. Suppose you have a string of length $n$ composed of just two digits one of which appears twice. Count the strings by hand for small values of $n$ and look for a pattern.

Comment: Thank you. I was almost sure there is no nice solution.I started with some cases by hand but as soon as I have more than two digits, problems are here. I just hoped a mathematicien was able to give me a solution, even complex.